# Is it possible to call a table-valued function in EF

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-4

It is possible to call a table-valued function directly, or do I need to wrap it with a stored procedure first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it's not in EF 4, and it will be available in EF 5.

[Refer TVF Support in EF 5 beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-table-valued-functions-june-ctp.aspx)

[Refer TVF Support not in EF 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/01/21/table-valued-function-support.aspx)

[New features in EF 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/03/22/ef5-beta-2-available-on-nuget.aspx)